# Launcher shows drives even when they aren't mounted

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus, mount

This has only happened in the last couple of days (after updates), but now my sidebar shows my two external hard disks even when they aren't mounted (or even connected for that matter). When they are connected and mounted, they are each shown twice.

For example, this is my sidebar when they aren't connected:

[image]

And when they are connected:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: With the drives disconnected, can you right-click on the phantom icons and click on "Unlock from Launcher?" (or "Eject")?

Comment: When I right click on the "phantom" icons, I have two options: Open or Format. It doesn't matter if the drives are connected or not. However on the two which are there when the drives are connected I get the full range of usual options.

Comment: What happens if you click Open (or format), for that matter?

Comment: Nothing happens if I click either of them. I just checked that now with both drives disconnected.

Comment: OK, I managed to fix it. I ran `unity --reset` and now it's fine.

Comment: Great, I was just going to suggest that provided you had no custom settings you'd mind losing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following command (with force option) could work as well:

`umount -f /media/Snoopy`

You could check what's exactly mounted by:

`mount`

command.

Try as well:

`unity --reset --verbose`